# How to use case_when with loop and regex?

Tags: r, regex, function, loops, case-when

I want to generate a new variable named `new_p` which takes the values of other variables based on `paste0`. My approach below produces the new variable, but does not assign the values correctly. It only assigns one value and returns `NA` for the other values of `lev`. Thanks for any help.

**My data:**

```
tempDF <- structure(list(d1 = c("A", "B", "C"), d2 = c(40L, 50L, 20L), 
    d3 = c(20L, 40L, 50L), d4 = c(60L, 30L, 30L), p_A = c(1L, 
    3L, 2L), p_B = c(3L, 4L, 3L), p_C = c(2L, 1L, 1L), p4 = c(5L, 
    5L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

lev<-levels(as.factor(tempDF$d1))

View(tempDF)
```

**My approach:**

```
for(i in seq_along(lev)){

func<-function(tempDF, i, lev){

newDT<-tempDF%>%
mutate(.,  
        new_p = case_when (
         d1  ==  paste0(lev[i]) ~ .[, paste0("p", "_", lev[i])]
        ))%>%
        as.data.frame(.)
        }

newDT<-func(tempDF, i, lev) %>%
        as.data.frame(.)

}

View(newDT)

newDT
  d1 d2 d3 d4 p_A p_B p_C p4 new_p
   A 40 20 60   1   3   2  5 NA
   B 50 40 30   3   4   1  5 NA
   C 20 50 30   2   3   1  4 1
```

**Expected output:**

```
newDT
  d1 d2 d3 d4 p_A p_B p_C p4 new_p
   A 40 20 60   1   3   2  5 1
   B 50 40 30   3   4   1  5 4
   C 20 50 30   2   3   1  4 1
```

**Edit: Barradas's function applied to a larger data:**

```
tempDF <- structure(list(d1 = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "C"), d2 = c(40L, 50L, 20L, 50L, 20L), 
    d3 = c(20L, 40L, 50L, 40L, 50L), d4 = c(60L, 30L, 30L,60L, 30L), p_A = c(1L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 2L), p_B = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L), p_C = c(2L, 1L, 1L,2L, 1L), p4 = c(5L, 
    5L, 4L, 5L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

View(tempDF)    

lev<-levels(as.factor(tempDF$d1))

func <- function(tempDF, lev){
  i <- match(tempDF$d1, lev)
  j <- match(paste0("p", "_", lev), names(tempDF))
  tempDF$new_p <- tempDF[cbind(i, j)]
  tempDF
}

newDT <- func(tempDF, lev)

Warning message:
In cbind(i, j) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)

View(newDT)

newDT
  d1 d2 d3 d4 p_A p_B p_C p4 new_p
   A 40 20 60   1   3   2  5     1
   B 50 40 30   3   4   1  5     4
   C 20 50 30   2   3   1  4     1
   A 50 40 60   3   3   2  5     1  //wrong, new_p should be 3, not 1
   C 20 50 30   2   4   1  4     3  //wrong, new_p should be 1, not 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need loops nor pipes to do what the question asks for, `match` and plain dataframe extraction can solve the problem.

```
func <- function(tempDF, lev){
  i <- match(tempDF$d1, lev)
  j <- match(paste0("p", "_", lev), names(tempDF))
  tempDF$new_p <- tempDF[cbind(i, j)]
  tempDF
}

newDT <- func(tempDF, lev)

newDT
#  d1 d2 d3 d4 p_A p_B p_C p4 new_p
#1  A 40 20 60   1   3   2  5     1
#2  B 50 40 30   3   4   1  5     4
#3  C 20 50 30   2   3   1  4     1
```

## Edit.

The following function, returns the correct output, with both the original data and with the bigger one.

```
func <- function(DF, levs){
  i <- sapply(levs, function(l) which(DF$d1 == l))
  j <- rep(match(paste0("p", "_", levs), names(DF)), lengths(i))
  i <- unlist(i)
  o <- cbind(unlist(i),j)
  o <- o[order(o[,1]),]
  DF$new_p <- DF[o]
  DF
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Rui_Barradas. This is great and very helpful!

Comment: Hi, Barradas. Again thanks for this. But when I apply the function to a larger data, it gives wrong output. For example, vide my edited question.

Comment: @Rui_Barradas, any thoughts?

Comment: @Rui_Barradas, Great. Thanks again for your effort to help me. This indeed works. Well done.